# Parse an image from json response Appcelerator Cloud?

Tags: javascript, android, json, titanium, appcelerator

I am uploading a picture to cloud using Appcelerator Cloud Services and want to retrieve it back in all sizes. Uploading is working fine but I am not getting the photo back. I am getting the `urls` in JSON response:

Here is my code:

```
    Cloud.Photos.show({
        photo_id: pid
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var photo = e.photos[0];
            waitDialog.hide();
            alert('Success:\n' +
                'id: ' + photo.id + '\n' +
                'filename: ' + photo.filename + '\n' +
                'updated_at: ' + photo.updated_at + '\n' +
                'urls: ' + photo.urls);

                alert(photo.urls.square);
                var image2 = photo.urls.square.toImage();

                var squareImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    top: "10dp",
                    left: "10dp",
                    image: image2,
                    height: Titanium.UI.SIZE,
                    width: Titanium.UI.SIZE
                });

                $.index.add(squareImage);

        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
```

and I am getting a JSON response like this (This is not original, as I am testing it in device)

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status":"ok",
    "code":200,
    "method_name":"showPhoto"
  },
  "response": {
    "photos": [
      {
        "id":"4d51d4186f70952d4c000006",
        "filename":"photo.jpg",
        "size":584344,
        "collection_name":"default",
        "md5":"589b8ad43ed20bf8e622d719642bc939",
        "created_at":"2011-02-08T23:39:04+0000",
        "updated_at":"2011-02-08T23:39:08+0000",
        "processed":true,
        "content_type":"image/jpeg",
        "urls": {
          "square":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_square.jpg",
          "thumb":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_thumb.jpg",
          "small":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_small.jpg",
          "medium_500":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_medium_500.jpg",
          "medium_640":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_medium_640.jpg",
          "large":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_large.jpg",
          "original":"http://storage.appcelerator.com/c3e1d292cb79ba7b9783d6cd45344719/photos/4d51d4186f70952d4c000006/photo_original.jpg"
        }
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

I want to get all images from the `urls`.

Do I need to parse it or anything else I need to do? Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign photo like this

```
squareImage.image =photo.urls.square;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. The thing is, `photo.urls.square` is not returning anything.

Comment: it is because the image has not been processed yet. take a look at the documentation. http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/photosizes-section-3 you need to specify the size you want a sync so it is immediately available